# How do I make a simple proxy server on my Windows Laptop for a Linux machine to proxy to the internet through

Tags: linux, windows, networking, laptop, proxy

I've had this link bookmarked for a while which works perfectly for me from a Mac or Linux machine

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116191/give-server-access-to-internet-via-client-connecting-by-ssh

How do I accomplish this with my setup? I have a windows laptop for work that I want my Linux dev machine to be able to proxy through

Are there any clear, simple instructions for doing this? I don't know a lot about networking and some of the terms get lost on me

Should I just use squid through WSL? I haven't tried this yet

Comment: Do you want an actual *PROXY* or is it enough to have internet connection sharing?  You mention `I don't know a lot about networking` which makes me think an actual proxy isn't what you need.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I think internet connection sharing might work for me. I will look into this. My work laptop is connected over VPN (we use globalprotect https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/sase/globalprotect) if that changes anything